# Javascript function with some input and output

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

There is a javascript question which was in an interview today for me. Can someone please help me understand the output of the question. Please note, I vaugley remember the correct syntax of code snippet given but I am sure you understand here what would be the question like.

```js
Function(x) {
  return (y) {
    return x + y;
  }
}
```

Question 1 - What is the output of Function(5)(6)

Question 2 - What is the output of Function(4)

Question 3 - What is the output of Function(7)

Comment: *"Please note, I vaugley remember the correct syntax of code snippet given but I am sure you understand here what would be the question like."* We actually can't. At least I personally can't make much of a sense of that syntax.

Comment: All of this is one big syntax error, so no output. Also, use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and try it there.

Comment: I converted it to a snippit so you can see that it does not run. It needs to be _runable_ for anyone to answer the question.

Comment: If you want currying it would probably be `11, function, function`

Comment: We could try to guess what the original was, but that's what we'd be doing: Guessing. (Perhaps well, but perhaps not.) Contact them and ask for the details of the question, saying you couldn't answer the question and want to learn more. (If they have a problem with that, you didn't want to work for them.) Once you have the real code, work through some tutorials and see if you can work out what the code does. Play with it. There's little better way to learn this stuff than to play with it.

Comment: @Jonasw: Lol what is currying stuff? :) BTW you wrote some sensible answer like I rated one below in this as right answer.

Comment: @learner currying means that a function returns a function. That creates a closure so some data is prestored this is sometimes useful, e.g.: `addToFive = add(5); console.log(addToFive(10), addToFive(2))`

Comment: @Jonasw: Thank you :)

Comment: The syntax is wrong, but the main idea behind that example is about **Curring**. See [A Beginner’s Guide to Currying](https://www.sitepoint.com/currying-in-functional-javascript/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean

```
function foo(x){ 
  return function(y){
    return x+y;
  }
}
```

Then `foo(5)` returns a function that takes another parameter, `(y)`.
So foo(5)(6) inputs 5 to `foo`, and 6 to `bar`.

`foo(5)(6)` returns `11`

`foo(4)` returns a `function(y){ return 4 + y;}`

`foo(7)` returns a `function(y){ return 7 + y;}`

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly I saw in question code snippet, but I am not into javascript, all I could do to learn is try to remember what I saw :( If I were one of these folks, I am sure to help someone like me as someone like you. :) I am afraid a lot of people curse me here :( I am newbie to JS :(

Comment: That is called **Curring**. See [A Beginner’s Guide to Currying](https://www.sitepoint.com/currying-in-functional-javascript/)

Comment: Yes, this was explained in the comments of the question.